# Running two maven projects in separate docker containers

Tags: maven, docker

I have two maven spring boot applications and I was set up two docker file for that.
Inside each container, I am performing the maven install.
The two containers are performing a lot of download for the dependencies and finally packing the application.

Since these two containers are built sequentially, Can I share the maven's local repository of the first container to the second container, so that the second container's maven install will skip the locally available dependency and only fetch extra libraries mentioned in its pom?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

We do something similar so that our builds are always clean. But to save time on the maven download, we use a docker volume mounted to the `m2` directory so that the downloads can be used between builds & docker containers.

```
docker run -v m2Repository:/root/.m2 some-image

docker run -v m2Repository:/root/.m2 some-other-image
```

First run takes a while, but the following builds are much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention, which environment you are running builds on, so I would like to share my solution for Bitbucket Pipelines CI.

We build our ~20 containers in Bitbucket Pipelines CI and every container is Java application with almost same set of dependencies. Bitbucket Pipelines CI uses Docker images for running builds (yes, [they are using Docker images to build Docker images](http://m.memegen.com/llhckr.jpg)). There is an option to specify which Docker image to use for builds.

To avoid downloading all dependencies over and over again and reduce build time, I built custom Docker image which contains all external dependencies of all our modules. All dependencies were gathered using Maven's command in each module:

```
mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=c:/projects/bitbucket-pipelines-baseimage/local-maven-repo clean install
```

After that I removed project's artifacts from temp repository "c:/projects/bitbucket-pipelines-baseimage/local-maven-repo" and built Docker image, which includes that temp repository. That image was deployed to Docker Hub and now all our build in Bitbucket Pipelines are using it. Build times were reduced drastically!